# Display Value Entered In asp:TextBox On Modal

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have an `asp.net` webform application and i want to pass the value entered in my `asp:TextBox` for the users name to then be displayed on my confirmation modal.

**HTML**

```
        <div class="form-group">        
            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtRemoveUser" CssClass="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3 control-label">Enter Name To Be Removed</asp:Label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtRemoveUser" CssClass="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

<!-- Confirm Delete Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="removeUserModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header ConfirmHeader">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm Removal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure you want to remove <b><%= txtRemoveUser.Text %></b> from the payday lunch list?</p>
                <p>If you don't, click 'No' and the removal request will not be sent.</p>                    
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer ConfirmFooter">
                <asp:Button id="btnRemoveConfirmYes" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Yes" OnClick="btnRemoveConfirmYes_Click" ToolTip="Click to request user to be removed from the payday lunch list." />
                <button id="btnRemoveConfirmNo" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" title="Click to close this screen. The request will not be sent.">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried the following `<%= txtRemoveUser.Text %>` but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to display the value the user entered without refreshing the page back to the server then you'll need to do it with JavaScript.  Server-side code runs *before the page loads*.

Comment: If you're calling the modal on the client side, it won't show the name. You need a postback to populate `txtRemoveUser.Text`. Alternatively, use javascript to read the name from the text box and display it.

Comment: yes, as @navigator said, use javascript to set the value dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%= txtRemoveUser.Text %>` will not work as it'll only output the textbox's value during the initial page load or post back. You will need to use JavaScript to retrieve the value client-side but you will need to know the ID of your control. This can be done using `<%= txtRemoveUser.ClientID %>`

It appears you are using Bootstrap's [Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) (which in turn includes jQuery). Their documentation has a section on [varying content](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target).

This will result in your code looking roughly like:

```
$('#removeUserModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var user = $('#<%= txtRemoveUser.ClientID %>').val();
  $('.modal-body b', this).text(user);
});
```

**Working code snippet (excluding .NET controls):**

```js
$('#removeUserModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var user = $('#txtRemoveUser').val();
  $('.modal-body b', this).text(user);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group">        
 <label for="txtRemoveUser" class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3 control-label">Enter Name To Be Removed</label>
 <div class="col-sm-3">
  <input type="textbox" ID="txtRemoveUser" CssClass="form-control" />
   <input type="button" value="Remove" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#removeUserModal" />
 </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="removeUserModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header ConfirmHeader">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm Removal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure you want to remove <b>[name]</b> from the payday lunch list?</p>
                <p>If you don't, click 'No' and the removal request will not be sent.</p>                    
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer ConfirmFooter">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Yes</button>
                <button id="btnRemoveConfirmNo" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" title="Click to close this screen. The request will not be sent.">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That approach works when you show the original value that was defined on the server; if you want to show the value the user changed to, replace the `<%=  txtRemoveUser.Text %>` code with:

```
<span id="removeUserLabel"></span>
```

And before showing the modal, use this script to copy it to the span:

```
$("#removeUserLabel").html(
     $("#<%= txtRemoveUser.ClientID %>").val()
);
```

Using jquery, or as plain JavaScript:

```
var span= document.getElementById("removeUserLabel");
var input = document.getElementById("<%= txtRemoveUserID.ClientID %>").value;
span.innerHTML = input;
```

And then the value will appear correctly.

Comment: Assuming he is using jQuery ;)

Comment: Good call - added javascript direct.  It's been a while :-D

Comment: @BrianMains It doesn't seem to work. I added the `<span>` and removed my bit of code and then i added the JQuery (as thats what i'm using) but it doesn't display. I know being `asp.net` that sometime my id's get "MainContent_" added so i even tried adding this infront of the "<%" but still nothing.  Just to point out though the "MainContent_" was NOT added to the `<span>` id

Comment: The MainContent_ is only added for controls with runat="server".  To debug, try doing in the immediate window (or throwing it inside an alert() call):
`$("#removeUserLabel").length` and `$("#<%= txtRemoveUser.ClientID %>").length` to see which one returns 0; if either do, this is a problem.